# Create variable to count occurrences of "yes" across rows using a for loop (r)

Tags: r, loops

I need to add a column, NumCap, that is number of 'yes' occurrences in Cap1-Cap6, using a 'for' loop. Below are the first 5 of 34 observations.

(In SAS I made an array of Cap1-Cap6 and applied IF Cap(i)='yes' THEN NumCap +1. I'm new to both but having a harder time doing this in r).

```
     Sex    AgeGroup Weight Cap1 Cap2 Cap3 Cap4 Cap5 Cap6 NumCap
1    male      young     12  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes    
2    female    young     15  yes   no   no  yes  yes  yes
3    male      young     15  yes  yes   no   no  yes  yes
4    male      young     15  yes  yes   no  yes  yes  yes
5    male      young     13  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowSums` to create the "NumCap".  Subset the columns of the dataset with `grep`, convert it to a logical `matrix` (`==`) and get the sum of TRUE in each row (`rowSums`)

```
df$NumCap <- rowSums(df[grep("^Cap\\d+", names(df))] ==  "yes")
```

Comment: When I run this I get the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Is there something else I need to do for this to work?

Comment: @So_New  Can you please check the `str(yourdata)`  Is it a `data.frame` object

Comment: I thought this was a problem so I did ‘Capture <- data.frame’. Would this be sufficient? Is there a way to handle this using the for loop?

Comment: @So_New  Sorry, I didn't quite understand `Capture <- data.frame`.  As I said earlier, if the dataset is a `data.frame`, it should work.  If it is a `matrix`, then you need `,` i.e `rowSums(df[, grep("^Cap\\d+", colnames(df))] == "yes")`

Comment: does this show that it's a data.frame? If so then I'm still at a loss. I appreciate your help by the way!                                                                                           > class(Capture)
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: @So_New Yes, it is a data.frame.  What is the output of `grep("^Cap\\d+", names(Capture))`